# How to set Text Appearance in Android manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to do the equivalent of

```
setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

in the manifest file for an Android app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```