# TextAppearance in theme

Tags: android, coding-style, themes

I want to set the text appearance in my theme to be TextAppearnance.Large.
Here is what I am doing in my styles.xml (my application is pointing to this theme in my manifest)

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">  
 <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>  
</style>
```

Problem:
My text is still being displayed small.

Question(s):

- What am I doing wrong in trying to use a predefined TextAppearance in my activity? i.e. How do specify this TextAppearance correctly?
- Where are the TextSizes for TextAppearance.Large/Medium/Small defined?

Comment: Take a look at this question which was asked earlier on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726897/how-to-set-text-appearance-in-android-manifest-file May be it can help.

Comment: Yes, I saw that post, but using `?android:attr/TextAppearance.Large` inside the item tags produces a compile error.

Comment: My answer here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8380153/102703

Answer (score 5):

First, declare the attribute as

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
```

But declaring text appearance or text color in a theme only affects text that has absolutely no style or attribute anywhere, including system-defined ones. If you add a

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text" />
```

without even the `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"` line that Eclipse throws in, it will be affected by this theme, but buttons and the like never will.

Answer (score -1):

themes and styles are defined in the themes.xml and styles.xml files of the sdk implementations in your environment (distinct ones for different android versions or sdk levels).

search your computer for themes.xml (you will probably find multiple instances of it in the "program files/android" folder on a windows 32-bit machine, for example).

[this post](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/01/styling-android-with-defaults/) explains how to customize these attributes.

you can also set explicit size attributes in your xml layout file, by modifying the [TextView tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) attributes:

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="15sp is the 'normal' size."  
    android:textSize="15sp"  
    />
```

[this post](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/) explains how to customize android fonts (including fontType, fontColor, shadow, bold, italic) directly in xml layout file.

Comment: Using style is the good way to avoid xml code duplication and obtain a coherent behavior for all the textview and be able to specify textView style like TextViewTitle, TextViewNormal... and so on.

Comment: I am not discussing the preferability of one method over another, simply answering the proposed question.  :)