# How to apply FontSize dynamically and programmatically without using XML in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, font-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the Font Size in a whole Application programmatically, Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704216/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-a-whole-application-programmatically-android)

This is my Code : I have created Spinner with a list of FontSize options. If I click FontSize "26" then it should be able to change in that specific FontSize. Below I have an EditBox. So if I clicked Fontsize as 40 and in a Italic style than usual Bold.  So I should be able to type inside EditBox with this selected "Font" : FontSize "40" and Italic style.

How could I do this programmatically in Android?

```
font=new Spinner(con);
option= new String[] {"Select Font Size","8","10","12","14","16","18","20",
                      "22","24","26","28","30","32","34","36","38","40","50"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(con,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,option);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

font.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) {
        option[1]="8";
       selectedItem= option[position];
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't bother reading the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) eh??

Comment: Actually, i wanna do it in globally. It shoud be applied for entire application. Not specifically to EditText alone . Even it should be able to apply it in my whole project. But really do not understand how to do entirely ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to change

textSize use `editText.setTextSize(20)`

font and style use `editText.setTypeface(yourTypeFace, Typeface.BOLD)`

**UPDATE**

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText{

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
void init() {
   this.setTextSize(20);
   this.setTypeface(yourTypeFace, Typeface.BOLD);
}

// method to change font settings
void setFont(TypeFace tf){
   this.setTypeFace(tf);
}
//add whatever method you want
}
```

and then instead of using `EditText` you use this class, and don't forget in your XML to use

```
<yourpackage.MyEditText
     android:layout_height=".."
     android:layout_width=".."
     ... />
```

Comment: This i have tried but i do not need this. My need is to apply it entirely

Comment: ah ok, then I guess you have to extend the required components and add methods to changes these settings

Comment: Yes, trying a lot . But not getting what exactly i needed.

Comment: How to extend the required components and add methods to changes these settings ? Could you suggest me please?

Comment: I updated my answer.. I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

The probable solution would be you create a base class which extends TextView, and use this text view class as edit text. Hope you are asking for size in first screen. In any case, u set the text size in the base class. This will solve your problem.

like u create this class in package com.example and class name is BaseTextView, then in xml file instead of  you will write

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the id of the EditBox.
Then selected item's position. according to that you can make a formula like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) {
    int p=(8+(pos*2));

    editText.setTextSize(p);
}
```