# change default font size of setting automatically in android?

Tags: android

I created a preference for setting (font size). And i define multiple `array.xml` for types mobiles and tablet (automatic) . I need that set a default font size for my setting (font size) automatically.

```
someCode.....getString("lstFontSize", "10"<======);I need set font size automatic.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
public static int resSize = 0;
public static int resSizeTablet = 0;
public static int size()
{
    String prf = G.preference.getString("lstFontSize", (resSize != 0) ? String.valueOf(resSize) :String.valueOf(resSizeTablet));
    size = Integer.parseInt(prf);
    return size;
}
public static int DefaultFontSize(Activity act){
    Display display = act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(dm);
    int p=isTabletDevice();
    if (p == 0) {
        int density=dm.densityDpi;
        switch(density){
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            return resSize = 10;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            return resSize = 10;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            return resSize = 14;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            return resSize = 18;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            return resSize = 24;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            return resSize = 28;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

public static int isTabletDevice() {

    boolean xlarge = ((G.context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);

    if (xlarge) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        Activity activity = (Activity) G.context;
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            return resSizeTablet = 24;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            return resSizeTablet = 20;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            return resSizeTablet = 28;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can use :

```
Conver.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,YourClassName.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create different folder for different default font size like

Mobile:-

```
res/values/dimens.xml(default)
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320 and nearer resolution)
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480 and nearer resolution)
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD)
```

Tablet:

-For tablet or bigger screen you have to create more specific folder like
drawable-

```
large.res/values-large/dimens.xml    (480x800)
```

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: i think this answer will help you to set default font size

Comment: @llya now i've given answer of that quetsion so i hope that it'll help for him

Comment: Don't post your answer more than once in same question. Edit your  answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706166/how-to-apply-fontsize-dynamically-and-programmatically-without-using-xml-in-andr) and this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704216/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-a-whole-application-programmatically-android) The first post is a duplicate and the other is not but they both are on the same page and most probably something which might help you. In case your whole app is just a bunch of textViews then you can dynamically change the font size of the textViews like this:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
myTextView .setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
```

Hopefully I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Define your FontSize in res-->values-->dimens.xml file like

```
<dimen name="fontSize14">14sp</dimen>
```

and for tablet or other phone you can set accordingly in their specific folder like
res-->value-sw360dp-->dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="fontSize14">16sp</dimen>
```

I am setting 16sp in sw360dp folder you can set as you want to

In TextView call `android:textSize="@dimen/fontSize14"` 
I hope i'll work for you