# EditText not support HTML font size tag in android

Tags: android, html, android-edittext

This is my html
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRDWf.png)
when i have set it on edittext then it not increases the edittext font size.

```
edittext.setText(Html.fromHtml())
```

any idea ?

Comment: it is magic if we can know what exactly You want......please rework Your question with formatted code snippet and exact describtion.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please see [ask]

Comment: yes this is the image link http://i.stack.imgur.com/aRDWf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the other options to setup `edittext` parameters.

Futhermore, do not use `<p>` to setup.
There is only several tag that are supported:

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font  color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

By the way, you can use something like:

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
et.setText(Html.fromHtml("Simple Text <B>Formatted Text</B> Simple Text Again"));
```

but this is ugly:)

Comment: In my app Create Record section
I have a font spinner that increase and decrease the font size on a edittext and then save this data on the server in Html format but In edit record section, When i have reconvert these data to same format then edit text not read this html.
What other idea you have?

Comment: Also font color tag is working but font size tag is not work

Comment: add spinner change value listener like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714426/1979882 and then change edittext fond values like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12706274/1979882

Comment: I have not change the font size of whole edit text, only selected text font size is increases and decreases.

Comment: @UjjwalJha , as wrote here, this is not possible to setup font size : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7740039/1979882

Comment: Thanks, Whole day i got same answer in google search
any idea to apply custom html tag handler ?

Comment: @UjjwalJha , write our own `Edittext`  that exends the usual. Or write another logic of the app. Or write our custom View (simpler than Edittext`).

Comment: @UjjwalJha , mark as accepted if you solved the problem of understanding.