# How to set font size globally and managed it by user

Tags: android, fonts

I want user to use SeekBar to choose the font size and apply it to whole app. I don't want to extend base classes e.g TextView. I'm thinking something like in styles.xml set font size.

```
<item name="android:textSize">X</item>
```

Where "X" is a font size load from SharedPreferences. Is this even possibile? Also I want that text will change dynamical in app. So if user select with SeekBar font size to e.g. 20dp. It will change instantly. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704216/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-a-whole-application-programmatically-android). But there is exemple with predefined font size and this is not I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't dynamically change values from resource files. This is how I would do it:

1. Store the font size selected by the user in `SharedPreferences`.
2. In every class, load the value from the `SharedPreferences` and apply it to all `TextViews`