# TextAppearance override style's fontFamily

Tags: android, textview, styles, material-components-android

I have a style for TextView with a custom fontFamily. Also, I have a separate style for my textAppearance.

When I set my TextView style and textAppearance style into single TextView, fontFamily became ignored. But everything workes when style set without textAppearace.

Style is set using [Paris](https://github.com/airbnb/paris) library from airbnb.

TextView style:

```
<style name="TextViewBold" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_bold</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

TextAppearance style:

```
<style name="TextAppearanceAllCaps">
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/anotherColor</item>
</style>
```

Styles set programmatically:

```
MaterialTextView(context!!).apply {
        style(R.style.TextViewBold) //Paris used here
        updateTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearanceAllCaps) //custom extension
        setText(R.string.some_text)
}
```

Extension code:

```
fun TextView.updateTextAppearance(@StyleRes resId: Int) {
    TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(this, resId)
}
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: put your textAppearance Style into Textview style as a item

Comment: @D_K I can't. Because this style is base for several TextViews. Using textAppearance I can tweak some particular things for each TextView

Comment: you can set textAllCaps and textcolor manually, so just set attributes for it

Comment: @D_K I agree with u, but I don't want to do these repetitive actions for each view. Also, if some changes to styling occurs, single place will be refactored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inherit the `TextAppearance` from a parent where the `fontFamily` is defined or add it in your custom `TextAppearance`.

For example:

```
<style name="TextViewBold" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
   <item name="android:textAppearance">TextAppearance.App</item>
</style>


<style name="TextAppearance.App" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1">
   <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_bold</item>
   <!-- .... -->
</style>

<!-- Inherit from TextAppearance.App -->
<style name="TextAppearance.App.AllCaps"> 
   <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Then apply to the `TextView` the style `@style/TextViewBold` and update the `textAppearance` using the `style/TextAppearance.App.AllCaps`

Comment: This changed the text appearance but `fontFamily` still ignored(

Comment: @Skullper Just tried, it works without issues.

Comment: Oh, sorry!
You're right it works. But I can't use such approach. I have `fontFamily` declared in base style. This style in different TextViews. I just don't want to duplicate `fontFamily` in `textAppearance`, because it shouldn't handle it. It should just use `fontFamily` declared in view's style

Comment: You don't need to duplicate it. Just add in the style <item name="android:textAppearance">....</item>. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gabriele. This approach doesn't fit my app architecture, but for others, it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:theme="your theme"
    />
```

Comment: As u can see I'm creating my view in code only. I didn't use any xml

Comment: see this answer hope this will solve your answer let me know if it will https://stackoverflow.com/a/17896729/12543430

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest this workflow for styling text:

1. Set any app-wide styling in a textViewStyle default style in your theme.
2. Set up a (small) selection of TextAppearances your app will use (or use/extend from MaterialComponent’s [styles](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/typography/res/values/styles.xml)) and reference these directly from your views
3. Create styles setting any attributes not supported by TextAppearance (which themselves specify one of your TextAppearances).
4. Perform any unique styling directly in your layout.

Comment: At this time I can't set textViewStyle in the app theme

Comment: Try inheriting from the parent font family then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who wanted to help!

I found an issue and a solution(for my specific case). In most cases, you can check the accepted answer.

ISSUE:

The style `fontFamily` attribute erases when `textAppearance` set programmatically. I've even tried to set my text appearance with some delay, to check if the UI thread wasn't overloaded, but it didn't help.
Also, I tried to set style without Paris, it didn't help too.

By the way, I didn't find out why :(

SOLUTION:

I have created XML file with my `TextView` element only(thanks for a tip @D_K). Then I set style and text appearance in XML and inflated it where I need it.
Only using this approach I achieved what I want.

P.S. If u will have a problem with text color, just set it as `@null` in text view style, then `textColor` from textAppearance will be used.